# Custom type as XMLAttribute

Tags: attributes, struct, xmlserializer

I have a custom `struct` type that supports implicit conversion to and from `string`. I can serialize this struct as an element without any problems with the using the `XmlText` attribute on a public property.

```
struct Test
{
    [XmlText]
    public string Value {get(...);set(...);}
}

class Other
{
    [XmlElement] // this renders as <TestElement>value</TestElement>
    public Test TestElement {get; set;} 

    [XmlAttribute] // this fails at runtime
    public Test TestElement {get; set;} 
}
```

However, I cannot serialize it as an attribute. Is there anyway to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[XmlText]` means to serialize the data as the text value of an element. It cannot be used for an attribute.

Comment: I kind of know that, what I want to know is how can I make it work with as an **attribute**, my type is implicit convertible to and from string, so if I could make it appear as a string it would work.